# How to declare a new variable inside a shell block in groovy script?

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to declare and use new variables inside a shell block in a groovy script.

For example, this shell block -

```
sh """
    export earlist='abc.ear,def.ear'
    echo $earlist;
"""
```

throws an error saying

> No such property: earlist for class: GroovyUserScript

If I add a *def earlist* before the sh, then it throws error saying -

> No signature of method: GroovyUserScript.sh() is applicable for
>   argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [
>   export earlist='abc.ear,def.ear' echo ;

Can someone please help me with how to declare and then use variable inside a shell block, in a groovy script?

Comment: use ${earlist} directly

Comment: use single quotes `sh ''' ... '''`. or you have to escape `$` sign: `\$`. when you use double-quotes groovy tries to substitute `$xxx` expressions in string with groovy variable values.

Answer (score 1):

After consulting with senior experts at my workplace, I found the solution I was looking for.

The problem with this code -

```
sh """
    export earlist='abc.ear,def.ear'
    echo $earlist;
"""
```

is that when I say $earlist, the compiler looks for a groovy variable named earlist and doesn't find it. Since earlist there is a shell variable, I need to escape the $. So, the correct code is -

```
sh """
    earlist='abc.ear,def.ear'
    echo \$earlist;
"""
```

Bonus TIL - if I access a groovy variable inside a shell block, the access is Read-Only. I can't edit the value of the groovy variable, even temporarily within the shell block. If I do want to do that, I can assign the groovy variable to a shell variable, manipulate the shell variable value, save the modified value in a file and when the shell block ends, read the file into the original groovy variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `triple single quoted string` instead, which doesn't interpolate variables:

```
sh '''
    export earlist='abc.ear,def.ear'
    echo $earlist;
'''
```

See here the documentation on `triple single quoted strings`: http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_single_quoted_string

Here a overview of the available string types in Groovy: http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_summary_table